# CDK v2 with HttpUrlIntegration route sub paths to the endpoint

Tags: aws-cdk

Is there anyway using the following

```
const api = new apigatewayv2.HttpApi(this, 'ProxyAPI', {});
api.addRoutes({
    path: '/proxy',
    methods: [ apigatewayv2.HttpMethod.ANY ],
    integration: new HttpUrlIntegration('ProxyIntegration', 'https://httpbin.org/anything'),
    authorizer: authorizerIAM,
});
```

This works fine

https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/proxy

I also want this to work

https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/proxy/foo

I'd want that to hit https://httpbin.org/anything/foo

Thanks

I've tried the following

```
api.addRoutes({
    path: '/proxy',
    methods: [ apigatewayv2.HttpMethod.ANY ],
    integration: new HttpUrlIntegration('ProxyIntegration', 'https://httpbin.org/anything'),
    authorizer: authorizerIAM,
});
```